# Why does this for loop only print one element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Could you help me with this problem I found on MDN?

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
var totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
var total = 0;

list.innerHTML = '';
totalBox.textContent = '';

var products = [
  'Underpants:6.99',
  'Socks:5.99',
  'T-shirt:14.99',
  'Trousers:31.99',
  'Shoes:23.99'
];

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var subArray = products[i].split(':');
  var name = subArray[0];
  var price = Number(subArray[1]);

  total += price;
  itemText = name + ' — $' + price;

  var listItem = document.createElement('li');

  listItem.textContent = itemText;
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}

totalBox.textContent = 'Total: $' + total.toFixed(2);
```

```html
<div class="output">
  <ul></ul>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I understand the logic but when I write only this part of the code below on my console, it returns only `"Socks:5.99"`:

```
var products = [
  'Underpants:6.99',
  'Socks:5.99',
  'T-shirt:14.99',
  'Trousers:31.99',
  'Shoes:23.99'
];

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var subArray = products[i].split(':');
  var name = subArray[0];
  var price = Number(subArray[1]);
}
```

And the `subArray` contains only that element. It seems like the `for` loop doesn’t work. Shouldn’t it give me an entire new Array with:

```
Underpants — $6.99
Socks — $5.99
T-shirt — $14.99
Trousers — $31.99
Shoes — $23.99
```

Comment: Loop calculates data for one loop at a time. Where's the line that print the output?

Comment: You are just added one item to the array

Comment: `subArray` is set to a new array in each iteration of the loop, it will never contain each item of the other array. For that you would not create it in each iteration and just `push()` items on to it or `concat()` to make a new array

Comment: Are you asking why your loop doesn’t work if you throw out everything except the three variable declarations? Why do you expect your loop to do anything useful? Your reduced code doesn’t produce any output. What code are you asking about and what exactly is your question?

Comment: You are not getting your expected output because `subArray` variable is getting re-declare in every iteration and at last it only holds the last value.

Comment: I think that is what OP wants @Ash but the append part to the list isn't working as expected

Comment: @lucabertoldi your code works as when run in the stackoverflow using run button, what else where you expecting?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I think he is asking for the second code snippet. First snippet is working fine already. He asked why the second one is not working after removing some lines from the first snippet.

Comment: Ok @ash now i get it and I think the provided answer says why!

Answer (score 3):

Your code works, you just have to store each iteration result somewhere, like in a new array. Here is an example:

```js
var products = [
  'Underpants:6.99',
  'Socks:5.99',
  'T-shirt:14.99',
  'Trousers:31.99',
  'Shoes:23.99'
];

var formattedProducts = [];

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var subArray = products[i].split(':');
  var name = subArray[0];
  var price = Number(subArray[1]);
  formattedProducts.push(name + ' - $' + price);
}

console.log(formattedProducts);
```

**Edit**

In your first code example, the result was stored directly in your DOM, inside the `.output ul` list element:

```
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');

  listItem.textContent = itemText;
  // list is defined outside the loop and will receive a new li element with the result of the iteration as textContent
  list.appendChild(listItem);
```

Comment: Not even sure if this is what op is trying to do or just wants to add each of the new subarray item to the created list element and repeat the whole process.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The OP snippet already does that. I thought the OP only wanted to understand how the code works bit by bit, so I wrote an example of how to store each iteration result somewhere outside the loop.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how the iteration result was stored in the first code example